# vuejs typescript property router does not exist

Tags: typescript, vue.js

I try to access router in my typescript class component:

```
import {Vue} from 'vue-property-decorator'
import Component from 'nuxt-class-component'
import {Getter, Action} from 'vuex-class'

@Component
export default class Login extends Vue {
    @Action login

    username = ''
    password = ''

    async submit () {
        await this.login({username: this.username, password: this.password})
        this.$router.push('/results')
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, I get:

```
error TS2339: Property '$router' does not exist on type 'Login'.
```

Comment: $router may be private in the declaration file, try (<any>this.$router).push('/results'). If that is working, then the declaration file is wrong. Hmm, have you tried "super.$router" as well? It may be protected

Comment: Apparently neither work. But this['router'] works.

Comment: you can try with this (this as any).$router.push()

Answer (score 15):

Shim the vue file and include `$router`:

Make a `typings` file called `vue-shim.d.ts`

Adjust your shim like this:

```
import VueRouter, { Route } from 'vue-router'

declare module 'vue/types/vue' {
  interface Vue {
    $router: VueRouter
  }
}
```

now `Vue` (in your case -- this) will have a property of `$router` and typescript won't complain.

Comment: I'd like to know if there' some official documentation about that. Also, is that required for Vue 3 projects, too?

Comment: @ShadowGames This post is 3 years old, so the answer above was exclusive to Vue 2.

Comment: It help for NUXT 3. Don't forget restart your VSCode after creating vue-shim.d.ts

Comment: For Vue3 it looks slightly different. You can check the documentation here: https://vuejs.org/api/utility-types.html#componentcustomproperties

Answer (score 13):

For the ones who are using Vue 3, don't forget to declare your components with `defineComponent`, otherwise TypeScript won't be able to infer the types:

```
<script lang="ts">
import { defineComponent } from 'vue'

export default defineComponent({
  // type inference enabled
})
</script>
```

Reference: https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/typescript-support.html#defining-vue-components

Answer (score 6):

Make sure you have the router imported in your main vue file:

```
import router from './router'

const v = new Vue({
  router,

  render: h => h(App)
}).$mount('#app')
```

This is how I write my components, but I think it is the same.

```
  import Vue from 'vue'

  export default Vue.extend({
    name: 'Login'

  })
```

Comment: The second code block fixes the issue.

The original problem was because TS didn't know the exported object was being used within vue.

Answer (score 1):

other answer don't work for me

but the code below works

```
import Vue from 'vue';

import VueRouter from 'vue-router';

...
  public rowClick(row: object, column: object, event: object): void {
      console.log(row, column, event);
      this.$router.push('/login');
  }
...
```

Answer (score 1):

In Vue 3, adding these lines to `vite-env.d.ts` got rid of the error:

```
import { Router } from 'vue-router'
declare module '@vue/runtime-core' {
  interface ComponentCustomProperties {
    $router: Router
  }
}
```