# Vue navigation with vue-router in Store using TypeScript and FirebaseAuthUI

Tags: typescript, vue.js, firebase-authentication, vuex, vue-router

I'm trying to learn Vue.js and have created a Quasar (Vue) project with TypeScript support, using Quasar CLI.

I'm using FirebaseAuthUI for authentication and have created a boot-file called firebase.ts. FirebaseAuth has a 'onAuthStateChanged', which is called each time a user logs in or out. The 'onAuthStateChanged' method is placed as a Store action (handleAuthStateChanged).

My problem is that there is no access to this.$router using Typescript in the store.ts file. Is it wrong to use navigation from a Store Action? Is this a Typescript problem? Or am I overlooking something?

**Project setup:**

'handleAuthStateChanged' is registered in App.vue

```
///App.vue

<script lang="ts">
import { mapActions } from 'vuex';

export default {
  methods: {
    ...mapActions('userStore', ['handleAuthStateChanged'])
  },
  mounted() {
    this.handleAuthStateChanged();
  }
};
</script>
```

```
///store.ts

const actions = {
  handleAuthStateChanged({ commit }: { commit: any }) {
    
    firebaseAuth.onAuthStateChanged(user => {
      if (user) {
        // User is logged in
    
        this.$router.push('/myPage'); //$router shows Typescript ERROR, but works???
      } else {
        // User is logged out
        
        this.$route.push('/login'); //$router shows Typescript ERROR, but works???
      }
    });
  },
  logoutUser() {
    firebaseAuth.signOut();
  }
};
```

Error message in VScode:

```
Property '$router' does not exist on type '{ handleAuthStateChanged({ commit }: { commit: any; }): void; logoutUser(): void; }'.ts(2339)
```

Comment: Did you ever manage to fix the actual TS error caused by eslint. Specifically gaining the use of 'this' in a type safe way in App.vue: mounted()?

Answer (score 0):

WHen you use:

```
          this.$router.push('/myPage'); //$router shows Typescript ERROR, but works???
```

you should first check if the route you are pushing is not already the current one.

Comment: Of course, - my mistake. Thanks for pointing this out. The browser error occurs, when reloading the mypage (it's already on that page and trying to push the mypage again).

However, I'm still puzzled about the TS error, any idea on how to tell TypeScript about this.$router ?

Comment: Is the store defined in your index.ts?

Comment: Yes, that was done by the Quasar CLI project creation.

Comment: I don't know then. Sorry. But good to have fixed the route duplicated route at least

Comment: Maybe this https://stackoverflow.com/a/54155543/7629020 it's about the router but seems a similar error pattern